# Shouldn't my flag have been declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

Ealier today, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802251/hook-into-the-wordpress-theme-customizer-save-action/16679837#16679837) in the [new answers to old questions 10K list](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions). It sounded like a new question, so I left a canned comment to the author, and flagged it as *not an answer*.

Then the author replied to my comment, and later updated the answer. After the edit, although it still contains a questions, it does sound like an answer. I guess I should have added a custom *nevermind* flag at that point, but I didn't. And a couple of hours ago, a moderator deleted the answer.

Now I'm feeling guilty, I'm not sure if it should have been deleted. What do you think?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the answer?

Comment: @Seth Sure, added.

Comment: Thank you :) The answer has been undeleted now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, these answers are always tough, because unless you read them carefully they seem like follow-on questions. I thought there was enough material addressing the problem at hand to make this a potential answer, so I undeleted it.

In the future, if you think you made a mistake with a flag, you can use a custom flag on the answer or question and explain what was off about your earlier flag. We'll gladly take a look at it again.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I fell like I did something clumsy, and wonder if I should bother the mods about it, or ask on meta.